# JSS SSR headless mode vs api only for personalization

Tags: personalization, jss

Are there in any difference in personalization usage when using JSS SSR headless mode vs jss api only mode (with layout services where can use personalization).

We are in process of getting jss license and trying to evaluate different options.
SSR headless mode and api only, both are using layout services to get personalized layout. Is there any benefit in ssr mode, only in terms of using personalization and analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headless SSR mode has the same functionality as headless client-side rendering, but using it results in:

- Improved client-side startup times (no DOM manipulation at page load time)
- SEO (crawler JS execution is quite buggy at best)

[This article](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8) goes into a lot of depth about SSR and the performance impacts thereof.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, was not sure if going in right direction.

Comment: @Akanksha if Kam answered is satisfactory, please don't forget to mark it as answered.